# How to fix labels not showing up in ListViews?

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

My issue is when I add in labels to my ListView they wont show.
I am binding the labels to objects inside "DummyClass". FirstName, LastName, RepId.

I have done plenty amount of research over this issue and have asked multiple people to help on this subject but nothing[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srcYl.png) seems to work.

```
<StackLayout>
                <ListView  x:Name="listView"
                           HeightRequest="100">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="Hello" 
                                           BackgroundColor="Red"
                                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                    <Label Text="Yes"
                                           BackgroundColor="Red"
                                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                    <Label Text="Wooohooo"
                                           BackgroundColor="Red"
                                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: if you hardcode text, do the labels show?  If so, then the problem is in your binding.  Also, there is no need for the multiple outer StackLayouts you have.  Just one will do the job.

Comment: When I hardcode text, the labels still wont show. I did take out the outer Stacklayouts. Though If I take the Stacklayout out beside the labels it gives me an error saying the "The property "View" is set more than once".

Comment: you need one outer stacklayout, containing your controls and ListView, and one StackLayout inside your template.  You might also try setting an explicit HeightRequest on your LIstView.  It would also help to see where you are assigning your ItemsSource .

Comment: @sjl5825 Hi , you can show screen shot after running project, this will be helpful.Perhaps it is obscured by the stacklayout view outside of the listview. You can set the background color of each stacklayout to see where the problem is.

Comment: Currently I do not have a ItemSource though I do have a screenshot. Just give me a bit and I will show you my updated code and the screenshot of the emulator.

Comment: Updated the post with new content with the code and a screenshot for the output. I have tried the HeightRequest and as it does show to change how many lines there are for the list, it still wont show the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what my issue was. It was the ItemSource. My ItemSource was not defined correctly. Fixed all the issues I was having. Thank you all for helping!